# Group by in LinQ List

Tags: linq, grouping

If i have a List that has values like

```
public class List
    {
        public string Category{ get; set; }
        public string SubCategory{ get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }           
    }
```

Eg:

```
Cat1
subCat1
3

Cat1
subCat2
4  

Cat2
subCat2
2   

Cat2
subCat3
4
```

How can i group the Categories and Show it? 
i tried this

```
var list2 = list
                  .GroupBy(t=>t.Category,t=>t.Subcategory)
                .Select(g=>(g)).ToList();
```

But looks like i am missing something

Comment: Show us what your variable `list` is.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample output...